# How do I set meta tag information in a view display based off the contextual filter?

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

I have a display in a view (page) which uses a taxonomy term id as a contextual filter to choose what content to display. I need to be able to change the meta tag based on the value of the taxonomy term id.

Our site is currently using the meta tag module, but I believe that this only lets me set generic meta tag information that will appear exactly the same on a page using this display. Can this module handle this problem?